# Add event to datalist option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input box that uses HTML5 datalist options, On select of one of this option or when someone types in the field, I want to dynamically add another input box.

```
d3.select('#inputBox').on('keyup', function() {
 // do this 
 addInputBox(0); 
});
```

The above code works fine for when I type in the input box.

```
d3.select('#inputBox').on('input', function() {
 // do this
 addInputBox(0);
});
```

I tried to use an oninput event as seen in the code above, it works for when an option is selected, but the problem is that it still works for when someone inputs into the field.

For every input, the addInputBox() function gets calles, this isn't what I want, I know there is going to be a better event listener I could use. I have tried almost everything, Please Help!

Comment: Please post your relevant code. You will get more help and less downvotes . a jsfiddle of your issue is ideal.

Comment: `<option>` tag doesn't register events. Personally I would replace with a select plugin that is a lot more flexible. Lots of them around

Comment: @Shan, thanks for the suggestion. I am quite new to this platform.

Comment: Can't you just check the input against the contents of datalist in the 'input' handler?